# What is $-.5^{-.5}$ as pertains to eventually trying to find $0^0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to find out what $0^0$ is. The limit on the positive side seems easy, $1$.  On the negative side, I get different values from different sources.

This seems to me to be easy... $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-.5}}$ which is $\frac{1}{.7071 i}$, which is $-1.4041 i$.

I have tried Excel, and it can't figure it out... and when i tried Google, it gave me $-1.4041$, no $i$.

Also, would this mean that $0^0 = 1$? $-1$, $i$, or $-i$?

Comment: $0^0$ is _undefined_. In different contexts it can be reasonably defined to have different value, that lead to consistent behavior in those contexts. Making sense of arbitrary powers of negative numbers is not straightforward.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: The only sensible value of $0^0$ in any context where its value really matters (that I have heard of) is $1$. But it does not follow from any exponent rules, and must be defined by itself.